# getTheme().resolveAttribute() alternative on pre-lollipop

Tags: android, declare-styleable, styleable

I have been struggling to obtain the styled attributes with the pre-lollipop API.

With lollipop, I use

```
final TypedValue statusBarColor = new TypedValue();
getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.colorPrimaryDark, statusBarColor, true);
STATUS_BAR_COLOR = ContextCompat.getColor(this, statusBarColor.resourceId);
```

This works flawlessly, I haven't found a similar way to do this below API version 21. (minAPI = 16)

I tried using the `getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes()`. But, I don't have the `AttributeSet` to provide to that method since I am using this inside an activity. Am I doing things completely wrong, or is resolving styled attributes not supported on API versions below 21?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
  TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
  getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorPrimaryDark, typedValue, true);
  STATUS_BAR_COLOR = ContextCompat.getColor(this, typedValue.resourceId);
```

No need of **android.R.attr.colorPrimaryDark**, instead you should use **R.attr.colorPrimaryDark** Thats all :)

Comment: That's a good one, I haven't even spotted that one, but this doesn't answer my question. The resolveAttribute method is not available on API 16 until 21

Comment: Are you using AppCompatActivity, then "resolveAttribute" is available there :)

Comment: Hmm, I don't know why Android Studio is complaining about this, but it isn't anymore now. Thanks!